# Javascript code block as a parameter for a function

Tags: javascript

Given this piece of code (simplification of a React component I came by):

```
const myFn = function(
  {otherFn = () => {console.log('inside myFn declaration'); return 'true'}}
  ){
      console.log('Inside myFn2 ', otherFn());
      foo(otherFn);
      bar(otherFn);
      ...
}

myFn({name:'some name', type: 'some type'});
// output:
// inside myFn declaration
// Inside myFn2  true
```

I don't understand what is going on there. What's this construct? I'm referring to what is inside 'myFn()'

This construct/code-block is being called no matter what argument (therefore it doesn't behave as a default parameter)

What's more, the purpose of it seems to be 'otherFn' being made available inside the implementation of the function so it can be passed as a callback to other functions.

If the goal was to have otherFn available inside myFn body, it could have been implemented (in a maybe easier way to understand) as:

```
const myFn = function(){
  otherFn = () => {console.log('inside myFn declaration'); return 'true'}
  console.log('Inside myFn2 ', otherFn());
  foo(otherFn);
  bar(otherFn);
    ...
  }
}
// Output exactly the same as above
```

There has to be a simple explanation of what this construct is, but I don't seem to be able to connect it with anything I know of JavaScript.

Any hints on what's going on?

EDIT to include some of the answers:
Interestingly, if I use this code like:

```
function myFn({
  name: 'some name',
  type: 'some type',
  otherFn: () => { console.log("other function"); return false; }
}){
  console.log('here');
}
```

it does not work :-( using either node or console of chomium 
In order for it to work, the ':' should be '=' because it is assigning default values.

More EDIT. 
I've chosen Thomas' answer because although others have hinted me in the right direction (thanks Benjamin, Ainitak and all) I failed to fully 'see' it until I read Thomas' detailed explanation.

Thank you guys you're the best!

Comment: It's abuse of default argument values.

Comment: combined with object destructuring

Comment: Also, it's not just you who finds the code unreadable, I would never pass code like this code review.

Comment: Hint: you _can_ replace the function that's called, e.g. `myFn({otherFn: () => console.log('boo')})`

Comment: Reference to such kind of abuses (which I don't like as well), can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: Benjamin: I have been considering whether it is some kind of 'abuse' of default args like you say. It would be an obscure way to achieve the end proposed in code sample #2. Ainitak: I understand what is object deconstructing, but there is no object being deconstructed there; since you can call myFn with no args and it is going to work just the same. I'll give you that the syntax is 100% like object deconstructing

Comment: @Ainitak: I had tried what you suggest (Hint: you can replace the function that's called, e.g. myFn({otherFn: () => console.log('boo')})) but... it does not work! Much to my surprise.

Comment: @Jaime i tried with `myFn({otherFn: ()=>(console.log('test'),15)})` and it worked fine. Maybe you were using your own attempt at recreating the `myFn`

Comment: @Jaime in Chrome 66 it _doesn't_ work if you call `myFn` with no parameters, generating this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'otherFn' of 'undefined' or 'null'.`.

Comment: To make it work without any parameters you can (but shouldn't) pass _another_ default parameter for that destructured object, i.e. `const myFn = function(
  {otherFn = () => {console.log('inside myFn declaration'); return 'true'}} = {}
  ) { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This combines two features:

default value for an argument:

```js
const fn = (value = 42) => { 
  console.log("value:", value);
}

fn(13);
fn();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

wich is basically a shorthand for

```
const fn = (value) => { 
  if(value === undefined) value = 42;

  console.log("value:", value);
}
```

And object destructuring as an agument

```js
const fn = ({ foo, bar }) => { 
  console.log(foo, bar);
}

fn({ foo: 10, bar: 100 });
fn({ foo: 13 });
fn(window.location);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

basically

```
const fn = (__arg) => { 
  let foo = __arg.foo;
  let bar = __arg.bar;

  console.log(foo, bar);
}
```

Just that `__arg` is just a value that doesn't have an actual name inside your function.

---

### Summary:

```
const myFn = function({
  otherFn = () => {
      console.log('inside myFn declaration'); 
      return 'true'
    }
  }){
      console.log('Inside myFn2 ', otherFn());
      foo(otherFn);
      bar(otherFn);
      ...
}
```

is just the combination of these two features: Object destructuring of an argument with a default value for that argument that just happens to be a function.

Works like this:

```
const myFn = function(__arg){
  let otherFn = __arg.otherFn;
  if(otherFn === undefined){
    otherFn = () => {
      console.log('inside myFn declaration'); 
      return 'true' //why 'true' as a string?
    }
  }

  console.log('Inside myFn2 ', otherFn());
  foo(otherFn);
  bar(otherFn);
  ...
}
```

> What's more, the purpose of it seems to be 'otherFn' being made available inside the implementation of the function so it can be passed as a callback to other functions.
>
> If the goal was to have otherFn available inside myFn body, it could have been implemented (in a maybe easier way to understand)

The purpose of this construct is to provide you (who uses/calls the function) with the ability to inject this method into the function as some property of the configuration object **and** provide a fallback/default, if you don't pass this config property.

Imo the only uncommon thing about this construct is that the type of this property is `function` and that they have chosen to inline the function that serves as the default value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thomas! I think that you have made a great job of explaining the whole thing in an easy to follow way. 
Now I can see it :-)  , it is object deconstructing (to get the part 'otherFn' in an object that the caller might pass if he/she wanted) plus default value (just in case 'otherFn = ...' is providing a default value for it). 

Brilliant and many thanks for the 'enlightment'!

PS why 'true' as a string? Don't mind it, I had been doing tests and changing things here and there, it has been the boolean but I changed it can't recall the reason.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I got lost in the sea of all the new and super confusing ES6 syntactic sugars, and no other resource managed to make it as clear and understandable as you did here. Excellent post ⭐

Answer (score 2):

It's object destructuring syntax for the function parameter, with an arrow function as the default initialiser for the `otherFn` property.

You can use it like

```
myFn({
    name: 'some name',
    type: 'some type',
    otherFn: () => { console.log("other function"); return false; }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally understood 'what is the construct there'. It is 2 things simultaneously:

- object deconstruction
- default parameter values for the one deconstructed part

Of course I know what each of these are, but the fact that the only part of the object being deconstructed was a function, which in turn was being provided with a default inline implementation got me all but confused all the time.

Also, I was at a loss of understanding why the implementation was done this way instead of some more readable way (eg inside the body of the function). 
As Thomas suggests, now I understand that that is a way for the caller of the function to provide an implementation for the inner function (which has a default implementation 'just in case').

It has had me thinking a while, but it is nice when you get to finally understand it. Thank you all!

Comment: I'm new to ES6 and that parameter list felt soo cluttered, messy and hard to understand. Shortcuts shouldn't be made at the expense of readability, imho.